# Selenium Manager is chrashing for chrome 115 and 116 and above

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, seleniummanager

I'm using 4.11.0 version of selenium and it has selenium manager now. But it is chrashing when I'm trying to run tests. Please help me with solutions:

I tried removing webdrivermanager dependency... but still it's chrashing.

Comment: Share your code and error stack.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.